# What is the best way to migrate one database from one server to another in SQL Server with the keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to migrate or Copy one database from one server to another server.
Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I used the SQL Server wizard to Migrate (Under the tasks) and it works fine except that I did not see an option to move the PKs and FKs with that . (Please let me know If I could do it)
2. I tried to generate the Script with PKs and FKs but the file size is around 10GB.
   Because the file is too large I use "`sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file here>.sql` " in CMD but it does not show the process.

So my question is, What is the best way to migrate or copy the database to another server with the Keys?

Comment: Fortunately we don't have to resort to scripting the whole thing for copy. Just take a copy-only backup and restore in the new server.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup the database on server 1.
Move the backup file to server 2.
Restore the database on server 2.

Comment: will this keep the keys?

Comment: Yes.  Backup and Restore will include all tables, data, users, views, procedures, etc.

Comment: @Christiano It copies **everything**. Tables, data, PKs, FKs, triggers, constraints, indexes, views, stored procedures, functions, users, permissions, synonyms, types and some more things too.